# No such file or directory in GDB

Tags: gdb

When I use gdb to debug my C program, I get the following error.

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /media/cby/E/C_File/gdb_learn/threads/test_threads 
warning: Cannot exec /bin/bash:/usr/lib/ccache:/home/cby$/.bin:/home/cby/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
warning:  -c
warning:  exec /media/cby/E/C_File/gdb_learn/threads/test_threads 
warning: Error: No such file or directory
During startup program exited with code 127.
```

And when I run list, I am able to print the program normally.

```
(gdb) list
2   #include <unistd.h>
3   #include <pthread.h>
4   
5   int x=0,y=0;
6   
7   pthread_t pthid1,pthid2;
8   
9   void *pth1_main(void *args);
10  
11  void *pth2_main(void *args);
```

And my C program and the compiled executable are placed in the directory where I am currently running.

```
Working directory /media/cby/E/C_File/gdb_learn/threads.
```

I have checked the [gdb related manuals](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html#Source-Path), but I didn't find the answer, so I am seeking help here.

Answer (score 0):

When GDB starts the inferior (the thing you want to debug) there are two choices.  The default is that GDB starts a shell, and asks this shell to start the inferior, all arguments are passed through the shell.  This allows things like file redirection, or shell wildcard expansion to work.  The alternative is to skip the shell, and just run the inferior executable directly, passing through the arguments.  There's a GDB setting for this `set startup-with-shell`, see [here for more details](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html#index-set-startup_002dwith_002dshell).

From the warnings you are getting, I assume you are using the default mode, where GDB starts the inferior through the shell.

To figure out which shell to use GDB will look at the `$SHELL` environment variable, if that variable doesn't exist then `/bin/sh` is used.

So, if my `$SHELL` is set to `/bin/bash`, and I ask GDB to debug `/tmp/test.exe`, then GDB will actually try to run this:

```
/bin/bash -c exec /tmp/test.exe
```

Now if we look at your warning:

```
warning: Cannot exec /bin/bash:/usr/lib/ccache:/home/cby$/.bin:/home/cby/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
warning:  -c
warning:  exec /media/cby/E/C_File/gdb_learn/threads/test_threads
```

This error is emitted when GDB tries to exec the shell process, but the exec fails.  The first line of the warning is the executable that GDB tried to start, and each subsequent line is an argument that was added.

So, where in my example GDB tried to run `/bin/bash`, in your example GDB tried to start an executable called `/bin/bash:/usr/lib/ccache:/home/cby$/.bin:/home/cby/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin` which obviously doesn't exist.

If outside of GDB, just at a shell prompt, you do `echo $SHELL` I suspect you'll see that same long string - this is your problem.  You could then change this environment variable to point to the correct shell, like this `export SHELL=/bin/bash`, restart GDB, and you should now be fine.

How did this happen?  I notice the first part of your `$SHELL` is `/bin/bash`.  I suspect in one of your bash init files you are incorrectly doing:

```
SHELL=$SHELL:/some/extra/paths
```

when you should be doing:

```
PATH=$PATH:/some/extra/paths
```

But this is just a guess.

If you really can't fix `$SHELL` by adjusting your shell setup scripts, you could always just ask GDB to start the inferior without using a shell at all, at a GDB prompt just run the command `set startup-with-shell off`.  This will work fine in your case as you are not passing any arguments to the inferior.

Comment: Your answer is cool, I just `export SHELL=/bin/bash` and run GDB successfully. Since I am a beginner, thank you for explaining the knowledge of starting GDB, I learned more details about GDB.